# Reveal Div with Hyperlink using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery Panel that opens when clicking a button.

However, I'd like a 2nd link at the bottom of the page which opens the same panel.

How do I achieve this?

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dkoke6w/1/) & my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
        $("#open").addClass("hidden");
         $("#close").removeClass("hidden");
    });     

    // Switch visiblility of the "Close Panel" button
    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
        $("#close").addClass("hidden");
        $("#open").removeClass("hidden");
    });

    });
```

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: $('#button2').on('click', function() { $('#open').click(); }); maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be so simple but if you trigger the click event of your button, it should make the effect which you need to achieve.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(){
    $("#open").click();
    });
```

Here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4dkoke6w/2/

if this is not exactly what you want, let me know and I can tweak it a little bit per your requirement.

Comment: That is absolutely perfect - and you're right, how simple! I'm looking forward to learning more jQuery now - thank you! :-)

Comment: you are welcome my friend :), kindly don't forget to mark it as answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your selector:

```
// Expand Panel
$("#open, #link").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
    $("#open").addClass("hidden");
    $("#close").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function showPanel(){
 $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
        $("#open").addClass("hidden");
         $("#close").removeClass("hidden");
}

// Expand Panel
$("#open,#second-button-you-talked-about").click(showPanel); 
//or    
$("#open").click(showPanel);
$("#second-button-you-talked-about").click(showPanel);

// Switch visiblility of the "Close Panel" button
$("#close").click(function () {
    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    $("#close").addClass("hidden");
    $("#open").removeClass("hidden");
});

});
```

(you should also store your jQuery elements in variables)

Answer (score 0):

use class instead of id

```
$(".opendivs").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
    $("#open").addClass("hidden");
     $("#close").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

give the class *opendivs* to all the links you want to open the div with